# gcloud run deploy as an http request

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

I typically deploy new updates to my cloud run instances on GCP using the CLI:

```
gcloud run deploy CLOUD_RUN_INSTANCE --image gcr.io/ORGANIZATION/IMAGE --region us-east1 --platform managed --allow-unauthenticated --quiet
```

How would I run this same command as an http request using [axios][1] from my firebase functions?

Comment: Have you already read the API documentation? https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest

Comment: @FerreginaPelona yes but couldn't find how to overwrite existing service using an image

Comment: Your question would benefit by showing details of what you've tried and errors etc. that you encountered. You can append `--log-http` to **any** `gcloud` command and it will output the underlying API calls. You can use this as a guide to writing your code. When you reference technologie such as `axios` that may be unfamiliar to others, please hyperlink to them.

Comment: @DazWilkin helpful thank you. I'm looking to input the cli command as args in the post request like the example I added above

Comment: There is no POST command that duplicates the CLI. The CLI implements multiple steps and uses multiple APIs to build and deploy a Cloud Run application. You must read the documentation and learn how to use the API. There are examples in several languages on the Internet that you can use for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks for including more details. What do you observe when you try this?  Are you aware that Google provides libraries (SDKs) for all its services (in Node.JS)? Your solution would benefit from using these. There appears to be **no** [Cloud Client Library for Node.JS](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference) for Cloud Run, but you can use [API Client Libraries for Node.JS](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) for any Google service. Is it a requirement that you deploy through Cloud Build? You could deploy directly.

Answer (score 2):

The answers above solves the task of deploying Cloud Run by using a call to Cloud Build and then Cloud Build deploys the new revision, nevertheless the question is very specific:

> `gcloud run deploy CLOUD_RUN_INSTANCE --image gcr.io/ORGANIZATION/IMAGE --region us-east1 --platform managed --allow-unauthenticated --quiet`
>
> How would I run this same command as an http request using `axios` from my firebase functions?

So we need to use the [`replaceService`](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.services/replaceService) method. The following code will do this by purely using `axios` and HTTP request. It's worth to mention that this is an snippet but can be adapted to different approaches like Firebase Functions, etc:

```js
const {GoogleAuth} = require('google-auth-library');
const axios = require('axios');


const create_revision = async () => {
  const auth = new GoogleAuth({
    scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
  });
  
  const token = await auth.getAccessToken();

  //TODO: Replace as needed

  region = 'REGION';
  project_id = 'PROJECT_ID';
  service_name = 'SERVICE_NAME';
  image = 'gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/IMAGE';

  //Get the current details of the service
  try {
    resp = await axios.get(
      `https://${region}-run.googleapis.com/apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/namespaces/${project_id}/services/${service_name}`,
      {headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`}}
    );
    
    service = resp.data;

    //Create the body to create a new revision
    body = {
      "apiVersion": service.apiVersion,
      "kind": service.kind,
      "metadata": {
        "annotations": {
          "client.knative.dev/user-image": image,
          'run.googleapis.com/ingress': service.metadata.annotations['run.googleapis.com/ingress'],
          'run.googleapis.com/ingress-status': service.metadata.annotations['run.googleapis.com/ingress-status']
        },
        "generation": service.metadata.generation,
        "labels": (service.metadata.labels === undefined)? {} : service.metadata.labels,
        "name": service.metadata.name,
      },
      "spec": {
        "template": {
          "metadata": {
            "annotations": {
              "autoscaling.knative.dev/maxScale": service.spec.template.metadata.annotations['autoscaling.knative.dev/maxScale'],
              "client.knative.dev/user-image": image,
            },
            "labels": (service.spec.template.metadata.labels === undefined) ? {} : service.spec.template.metadata.labels,
          },
          "spec": {
            "containerConcurrency": service.spec.template.spec.containerConcurrency,
            "containers": [{
              "image": image,
              "ports": service.spec.template.spec.containers[0].ports,
              "resources": {
                "limits": service.spec.template.spec.containers[0].resources.limits
              }
            }],
            "serviceAccountName": service.spec.template.spec.serviceAccountName,
            "timeoutSeconds": service.spec.template.spec.timeoutSeconds
          }
        },
        "traffic": service.spec.traffic[0]
      }
    }

    //Make the request
    create_service_response = await axios.put(
      `https://${region}-run.googleapis.com/apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/namespaces/${project_id}/services/${service_name}`,
      body,
      {headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`}}
    );

    console.log(create_service_response.status)

  }catch (err) {
    console.error(err.response.data);
  }
};
```

This is the minimum `body` needed to create a new revision without modifying any previous configurations. As well to make any more customizations, the [API docs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.services/replaceService) can be helpful. The code was created by analyzing the output of the command by adding the `--log-http` flag.

Of course this is a little more complicated than using the Cloud Build approach, but this answers the question and can be helpful for others.

Answer (score -1):

Got it working using the following

```
try {
async function updateTheme() {
  let token: any
  const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(firebaseClientEmail, '', firebaseKey, [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
  ])

  await jwtClient.authorize(async function (err: any, _token: any) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('JWT ERROR: ', err)
      return err
    } else {
      token = _token.access_token.split('.')
      token = token[0] + '.' + token[1] + '.' + token[2]

      const deploySteps = [
        {
          name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud',
          args: [
            'run',
            'deploy',
            `${name}`,
            '--image',
            `gcr.io/${googleCloudProject}/theme-${theme}`,
            '--region',
            'us-east1',
            '--allow-unauthenticated',
            '--platform',
            'managed',
            '--quiet',
          ],
        },
      ]

      const deployRevisions = async () => {
        await axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: `https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${googleCloudProject}/builds`,
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
          data: {
            steps: deploySteps,
            timeout: '1200s',
          },
        })
          .catch(function (error: any) {
            console.log('ERROR UPDATING THEME: ', error)
            return
          })
          .then(function (response: any) {
            console.log('SUCCESSFULLY DEPLOYED THEME UPDATE')
          })
      }

      if (token) {
        deployRevisions()
      } else {
        console.log('MISSING TOKEN')
      }
    }
  })
}

await updateTheme()

} catch (e) {
    console.log('tried updating theme but something went wrong')
    return
}
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question but the task of deploying to Cloud Run. The question (in fact your own question) is about deploying a Cloud Run revision using the API (Cloud Run REST API) because you wanted to use HTTP requests but instead you're using Cloud Build as intermediary which at the end executes the same command. Then the calls are to Cloud Build and not to Cloud Run and I'd say this is a workaround considering how the question is written

Comment: @FerreginaPelona my question asks how to use axios to update my cloud run instance and the above code does exactly that so I consider it an answer

Comment: `gcloud run deploy CLOUD_RUN_INSTANCE --image gcr.io/ORGANIZATION/IMAGE --region us-east1 --platform managed --allow-unauthenticated --quiet How would I run this same command as an http request using [axios][1] from my firebase functions?` is not the same as `how to use axios to update my cloud run instance`

Comment: @FerreginaPelona how is it not?

Comment: You modified your question after posting it. In your original question (which some of us can read), you used axios POST. Your answer is a solution for a different question.  @ferregina-pelona put in effort with her own time and then you ignored her correct answer to then post an answer for a modified problem.

Comment: just saw @FerreginaPelona's answer which was not posted until today. I would say my answer is what I was looking for since I was able to use the same CLI tags in my axios request however both answers are helpful